# How to specify the order of custom column and existing column

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on the below code, and am interested in how I can change the order of added custom column. As you can see I am adding 3 columns `DifficultyLevel`, `ShortTitle`, `ShortText` but these are all adding to the end of column

> Name | Date | Project | Level | Stage | Phase

but what I want is display them in this order

> Level | Phase | Project | Name | Stage | Date

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 't4a_remove_unwanted_columns');
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 't4a_add_post_columns', 5);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 't4a_get_post_column_values', 5, 2);

// Remove unwanted columns
function t4a_remove_unwanted_columns($defaults){
    unset($defaults['title'],$defaults['date']);
    return $defaults;
}

// Add new columns
function t4a_add_post_columns($defaults){
    // field vs displayed title
    $defaults['DifficultyLevel'] = __('Level');
    $defaults['ShortTitle'] = __('Stage');
    $defaults['ShortText'] = __('Phase');
    return $defaults;
}

// Populate the new columns with values
function t4a_get_post_column_values($column_name, $postID){
    if($column_name === 'DifficultyLevel'){
        echo get_post_meta($postID,'DifficultyLevel',TRUE);
    }
    elseif($column_name === 'ShortTitle'){
        echo get_post_meta($postID,'ShortTitle',TRUE);
    }
    elseif($column_name === 'ShortText'){
        echo get_post_meta($postID,'ShortText',TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't return the defaults in `t4a_add_post_columns` , but set your own array instead... then it will should only show the columns in your array.

Comment: Hi Howard, can you please let me know how to set the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just set your own array for the `column_names` - there's no need to unset the other ones.  The `manage_posts_columns` you can filter the entire thing.

```
// You can remove this:
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 't4a_remove_unwanted_columns');


// Add new columns
dd_filter('manage_posts_columns', 't4a_add_post_columns', 5);
function t4a_add_post_columns($defaults){
    return array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'ID' => __('Order ID', 'text_domain'),
            'DifficultyLevel' => __('Level', 'text_domain'),
            'ShortText' => __('Phase', 'text_domain'),
            'Project' => __('Project', 'text-domain'),
            'title' => __('Name', 'text_domain'),
            'ShortTitle' => __('Stage', 'text_domain'),
            'date' => __('Date', 'dd_theme'),
        );
}
```

[image: screenshot]